# Do new subscribers automatically get added to a campaign on Mailchimp with a certain sending audience?

Tags: mailchimp

I am estimating to have new subscribers added to my audience throughout the next month, however, I would like to set up scheduled email campaigns to send while I'm away. Do new subscribers automatically get added to a campaign when they subscribe and get added to a certain audience? Or do only the people who were subscribed before I set up the scheduled email get the campaign sent to them?